# How do I filter for a date using Developer Mode In Excel without VBA if possible?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

[image]

This workbook is doing a partial search. I am having trouble doing the same for Date. I want to be able to either put MM/YYYY or YYYY or full date MM/DD/YYYY. F3:I4 are generated by the filter function in F3.

F2, G2, and H2 have text box from Developer ribbon and are linked to its corresponding box location (e.g. F2 text box is linked to F2).
The Formula in F3 is:

```
=FILTER(A1:D6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,A1:A6))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,B1:B6)),"No Match Found")
```

Comment: would you be willing to change the search date into 3 inputs, Search day, Search Month(as number), and Search Year?

Comment: Either that, or two, start date and end date?

Comment: Hello Scott, I think the 3 inputs (Search day, Search Month(as number), and Search Year) would work best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you dates in three boxes:

- Search Day
- Search Month(as number)
- Search Year

Then your formula is:

```
=FILTER(
    A1:D6,
    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,A1:A6)))*
    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,B1:B6)))*
    (IF(H2<>"",DAY(C1:C6)=H2,TRUE))*
    (IF(I2<>"",MONTH(C1:C6)=I2,TRUE))*
    (IF(J2<>"",YEAR(C1:C6)=J2,TRUE)),
    "No Match Found")
```

[image]